# Issue in sticky footer content in html5

Tags: css, html

I have created simple webpage using html5 and css.

I have created sticky footer with 4 columns and each column have vertical navigation menu.

Here is my code:

```
<footer>

<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-column" id="footer_column1">
Home
</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column2"> 
about us 

</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column3">
contact us
</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column4">
Blogs  

</div>

</div>
</footer>
```

and this is for css:

```
  #footer {
   position:absolute;
   clear:both;
   bottom:0;
   color:#000;
   width:100%;
    height: 50px;
   background:#fff;
   left:0;

}
.footer-column {
  float: left; /* Push the div as far up-left as it can be put */
  width: 25%; /* Make sure to subtract the padding */
  padding: 10px; /* We want padding on all sides to make things look nice */
  text-align:center;
}
```

Now page looks like :  s22.postimg.org/l0l6y85o1/Untitled_1_copy.png

If i increase the height of footer, it will be hidden background of slideshow.

Can anyone help me, how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a Z-index issue.

Comment: better post a fiddle or a test link of the site, it would be helpful to sort out the issue!!

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D, but now, half of the slider hidden...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given absolute positioning to footer so it will stay there, now your page is basically overlapping it. You should use relative layout for your page.

I would suggest you to use **bootstrap** for this. Here is a simple [example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) or [this](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/).

**Regarding z-index** - If you will give higher z-index to your footer say 999999 then it will be on top (higher than other elements on page).

Z-index will not actually help you with positioning. Always something will be hidden. If you want your footer to be right at bottom of the page then do not use absolute positioning and it will be pushed down.

Try:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 100px;

}
```

Comment: If i put position:relative for footer, it shows like, footer placed up in the slideshow. like this http://s9.postimg.org/9gcyy4ze7/Untitled_2_copy.png

Comment: I am talking about relative for html. Please check the examples

Comment: then please create a fiddle for your overall html, css and JS. It is difficult to help otherwise

Comment: it have lot yar.. not easy for whole work with jsfiddle.now my page looks like this, http://s22.postimg.org/l0l6y85o1/Untitled_1_copy.png. so now i need to know,how to increase height of footer?.. can you please help me

Comment: your footer is right at the bottom. What else do you want now? Check the code it should work. I have edited the answer. If you want something else then please edit your question.

Comment: nothing change from your answer, when i increase the height of footer, it will going to be hidden.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63382/discussion-between-deepika-and-anuj-yadav).