# Issue in sticky footer in HTML5 and CSS

Tags: css, html

Here is my code:

```
<footer>

<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-column" id="footer_column1">
<nav class="footer-link">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column2"> 
<nav class="footer-link">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column3">
<nav class="footer-link">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

</ul>
</nav></div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column4">
<nav class="footer-link">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

<li>Home</li>

</ul>
</nav>
</div>

</div>
</footer>
```

I have created sticky footer using HTML5 and CSS.

and CSS:

```
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   clear:both;
   bottom:0;
   color:#000;
   width:100%;
   height: 100px;
   background:#fff;
   margin-top:100px;
   left:0;

}
.footer-column {
  float: left; /* Push the div as far up-left as it can be put */
  width: 25%; /* Make sure to subtract the padding */
  padding: 10px; /* We want padding on all sides to make things look nice */
  text-align:center;
}

.footer-column .footer-link ul li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
}
```

and css for wrap is, `#wrap{width:100%;}` now page look like this, http://s28.postimg.org/qrt1vysy5/Untitled_1_copy.png.

May I know, why I can't set correct height of my sticky footer?

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: you've already posted the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462275/issue-in-sticky-footer-content-in-html5 here, right??

Comment: still, i didn't get solution @Aru

Comment: until unless you post a sample fiddle code, it is difficult to sort out the exact issue!!

Comment: @Aru The specific issue in this case is he thinks he wants an absolutely positioned footer div for some reason, even though its already contained inside the footer element. The answer I provided *is* correct to creating a "sticky" footer.But you're right, he hasn't included enough code to see how many html mistakes he made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link should help you figure it out](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

Relevant code:

```
#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 180px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -180px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 180px;
    clear:both;}
```

Comment: i think this is not correct code @charles, because don't add negative value . thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using negative margins here. It's just specifying that you want your footer which is included inside main to occur within the padding.

[And a reference, because why not](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/).

Comment: but from your answer, how to add main.. i don't have main.. i am using wrap.. so may i use style padding-bottom: 180px; for wrap?

Comment: @deepika You probably ought to clean up the html here. You're using the HTML5 footer tag, plus a div with id footer. The id names in the css file shouldn't be treated as gold. Just use them to fit your purpose.

Comment: can you see this link http://www.omines.nl/.. I need to show like this site's footer..can you able to help me?

Comment: @deepika, yeah I can. But you need to be able to put all of the relevant code you have in a format that best suits troubleshooting. Aru made it pretty clear that he'd help too if you used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @deepika, you're going to find *extremely few* people here that are willing to help someone unwilling to help themselves.

Comment: just help me with sample example,, and as same as this link's footer http://www.omines.nl/

Comment: @Aru, I've reported this post to the mods already. We're not going to be able to get sufficient details about deepika's problem here. He's made that painfully clear.